# How to add delay in a process chosen by scheduler (Linux kernel)?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, archlinux

**I want to change the Linux kernel scheduler such that for any process, there should be a system call to reduce the chances that the process would be selected for being dispatched.**

More specifically, if a certain process is chosen by the scheduler. The system call must pass on information, the additional delay (user input) to the scheduler such that anytime the said process is chosen by the scheduler, it adjusts the vruntime of the said process so as to delay its selection.

It would be a lot of help if I could get any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Seems to me like you want to reinvent the wheel. Check out [`man 7 sched`](https://manned.org/sched.7), in particular `nice(2)` and `setpriority(2)`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli thanks for help :), also do you have idea how to select process for adjusting vruntime?

Comment: If you mean in kernel code then nope, sorry, I don't know much of the inner workings of the scheduler.